# cloud spanner IAM permission, restrict access to database

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I want to have a cloud spanner instance used for a multitenant application, and what I'm looking for is restricting a service account to access only a database on cloud spanner.
As per [docs](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/iam#iam-policy-management), there are primitive roles defined so that we can restrict access to instances with IAM conditions, but I can't find a way to restrict to databases inside an instance.

I'm looking for `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost';` on cloud spanner.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking to set permissions for a specific database or for all databases inside an instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the permission directly at the [database level](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/grant-permissions#database-level_permissions). Select, your instance, in it, your database(s), go to the info panel and add the permission that you want to the account (user account or service account).

It's important to do it at the resource level (the database) because if you do it in the IAM page, you are at the project level and you grant the access to all Spanner database.

Comment: this solution still does not anwser the IP or host restriction option

Comment: @matikepson: it depends on what do you want to do.

Comment: i think i am looking for something like this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/259370132